# <q:set var="quid" value= "x" scope="session"/>

Tags: javascript, java, spring, hibernate, jstl

I have a function with parameter x how to set in JSTL because I m getting string when I m giving values as "x".

**JS:**

```
function test(x)
{                         
   <q:set var="quid" value="x" scope="session"/>
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="primary-button">
   <button ><a href="/pro/usercontrol/answ" onclick="test(${c-nFilters+1})" name="qusid"
      >Give Answer</a>
   </button>
</div>
```

the value is set as string x not with the value.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript runs at the client machine and JSP runs at the server machine. The only communication tool between those is HTTP.it requires a HTTP request from the client to the server by invoking HTTP requests.